# Can we change "apikey'" string in sendgrid

Tags: email, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to send emails. I followed [this](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate) guide to integrate SMTP relay.

In sendgrid they required "apikey" string to be set as username.
[image]

All configurations are successful but I am receiving email with this "apikey" string, like this: apikey <from_email_address>

This should be something like this instead of "apikey" string":
[image]

When I change the username (apikey in my case) then it starts showing **bad username** etc.

I'm new to sendgrid so not sure how we can achieve this but I believe no one would be sending emails to customers with this "apikey" string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Support team helped with this as it's a configuration which we need to set in `deployment.toml` file in WSO2 Identity server (I tried with version 5.11.0).

This block of code is required to configure sending email from WSO2 Identity server.

```
[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "wso2iamtest@gmail.com"
username= "wso2iamtest"
password= "Wso2@iam70"
hostname= "smtp.gmail.com"
port= 587
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= true
signature = "ABC.com"
```

We need to add a value in `signature = "Support"` in order to receive emails with proper sender name. for example `Support <test@support.com>`

It is documented here:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-email-sending/